# Decouple ViewModel from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

How can I decouple a ViewModel from a Fragment?

With Jetpack Compose, I could create a CreateEventScreen like this:

```
@Composable
fun CreateEventScreen() {
    val uiState = createEventViewModel().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    EventFormComponent(
        state = uiState,
        callbacks...
    )
}

@Composable
fun EditEventScreen() {
    val uiState = editEventViewModel().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    EventFormComponent(
        state = uiState,
        callbacks...
    )
}
```

I was able to decouple the EventFormComponent from the actual ViewModel.
With that garbage views xml system, however, the best practice apparently
is to instantiate the ViewModel in the fragment itself:

```
class EventFormFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

This makes it harder to reuse EventFormFragment for creating and editing events.

I tried creating a custom view EventFormView instead of a fragment, however custom views don't have access to things like registerForActivityResult, dialogs.. Meaning I'll lose some reusability.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly have a viewModel in a Composable.

```
@Composable
fun CreateEventScreen() {
    val eventViewModel: SomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = EventViewModelFactory())


    val uiState = eventViewModel.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    EventFormComponent(
        state = uiState, // 
        callbacks...
    )
}
```